# Why does Axiom 3 of Sigma Algebra Mean "All" Possible Unions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading about sigma algebra and the third axiom states that

$A_1,A_2,... \in \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A_1 \cup A_2 .... = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in F  $

Reading it as is my first impression is that we are taking the union of all events (sets) in $\mathcal{F} $  however all references explain it as being closure of $\mathcal{F}$ under taking the union of a selection of events in $\mathcal {F}$. Why does the axiom as stated mean so ?

**PS:** Had the axiom meant my first impression it always lead to $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i  =\Omega $ since the complement of an event is always located in $\mathcal{F}$ and $A\cup A^c = \Omega $.

Comment: It means that given a sequence of elements of $\cal F$ then their union is in $\cal F$.  As an example, if $A_n=(1/n,1)\subset\Bbb R$ then $\bigcup A_n=\bigcup(1/n,1)=(0,1)\in\cal F$.

Comment: Usually $\cal F$ is uncountable, so one cannot list its elements as a sequence.

Comment: My question is why do we take for example unions of 2 events , 3 events and so on when the notation says take all the union of all events $A_n$.

Comment: Say $\Omega = {a,b,c,d}$ why isn't K = {${\phi, \{a\, \{b\}, \{b,c,d\} , \{a,c,d\}, \Omega   } $ a sigma algebra ? Why do we have to include $\{a,b\}  $ and its complement $\{c,d\} $ into the set? The union $\bigcup A_n$ will give $\Omega$ and will be $\in K$

Comment: This is a general form of countable unions. Since $\phi \in \mathcal{F}$, you can set $A_i = \phi$, for all $i > n, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The way to read "$A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{F}$" is **not** that $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ enumerates all of $\mathcal{F}$. This is just saying "$A_1,A_2,\ldots$ is an arbitrary (countable) sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take your example to explain. You have $\Omega = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and $K = \{\phi, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{b, c, d\}, \{a, c, d\}, \Omega\}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$. For $K$  to be a sigma algebra, all three axioms need to be satisfied. I'll go over each one:

1. $\Omega \in K$, which is true.
2. $\forall A_i \in K, A_i^c \in K$, which also holds for $K$.
3. $A_1, A_2, \dots\in K \implies \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in K$. This does not hold in $K$. For example, consider $A_1 = \{a\}$, $A_2 = \{b\}$ and $A_i = \phi, \forall i >2, i\in \mathbb{N}$, then we must have $\{a, b\} \in K$ which is not true.

Therefore $K$ cannot be a sigma algebra. Infinite unions imply finite unions as well. So for any two (or more) events in $K$, their union must exist in $K$.

Comment: Thank you learner I still have a problem with the notation though doesn't $\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ mean taking the union of all the sets inside $K$ ?

Comment: Union of all sets would simply give you $\Omega$ which is guaranteed by axiom 1

Comment: And when you say $A_i = \phi \forall i>2$ are you assuming we have "many $\phi$'s"

Comment: Since you can set $A_i$ to be of your choosing it doesn't necessarily mean different elements of sigma algebra. You can set $A_i$ to be $\phi$ for all $i$, if you wish. The purpose of $A_i$ is to associate a set with each entry in sigma algebra

Comment: Aha!! I think I got you .... So basically $A_i$ is just any element from the set $K$ that we assign based on our desire .. Right?

Comment: $A_i$ is just any set found in $K$ and we can repeat our selection infinitely many times

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!